# Detecting QTcpSocket disconnect with a pointer to QIODevice

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork

I am writing a simple network application that will be sending and receiving TCP messages to a single listener. I use a context class to wrap much of the communication logic as such:

```
class context : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setDevice (unique_ptr<QIODevice> device);
    void sendMessage (message msg);

signals:
    void newMessage (message msg);

private:
    unique_ptr<QIODevice> m_device;
}
```

A generic `QIODevice` is given to the object instead of the concrete subtype `QTcpConnection` so that the logic can be tested without a network connection. I expected that any network errors would be presented as IO errors from the `QIODevice`. However, if the host disconnects, the `QIODevice` does not emit a signal. The `QTcpConnection` *does* emit a signal (`disconnected`) but the underlying `QIODevice` remains open, continues to allow reads and writes, and does not appear to give any notification of the error. My confirmation that the socket does see the disconnect is that the error string in `QIODevice` changes from "Unknown error" to "Socket is not connected"; but checking for an error string seems like a hack that shouldn't be necessary.

Is there actually some way to detect this kind of error with only the base class? If I am required to pass in the `QTcpSocket`, is there a way that I can still keep unit tests that do not require a client-server connection?

Comment: imo you should set up a proxy in between, so you have some `unique_ptr<DataSource>` or something, and give a concrete implementation (like say `class TcpDataSource : public DataSource`) where it has a composite `QTcpConnection`, and in your unit tests, you would call `setDevice` with some mock `DataSource`. Its another level of indirection for the benefit of being able to stub, plus maintenance shouldn't be too big of a concern if you only plan to use `QTcpConnection` in practice. If it is, I'm sure there are other solutions.

Comment: *"However, if the host disconnects, the QIODevice does not emit a signal. The QTcpConnection does emit a signal"*, this does not make sense to me. You have just one actual object instance, right? So it either emits the signal or not, "both" is impossible.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the code you are not showing. Please create a MCVE which duplicates the problem.

Comment: The device emits the signal, but I cannot connect to it because I've got a pointer to a superclass. In order to connect to the signal I would have to downcast to the QTcpSocket (which may fail) and then connect.